# Oracle Substring after specific character

Tags: regex, oracle, substr

I already found out I need to use substr/instr or regex but with reading the documentation about those, I cant get it done...
I am here on Oracle 11.2.

So here is what I have.
A list of Strings like:

```
743H5-34L-56
123HD34-7L
12HSS-34R
23Z67-4R-C23
```

What I need is the number (length 1 or 2) after the first '-' until there comes a 'L' or 'R'.

Has anybody some advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
regexp_replace(string, '^.*?-(\d+)[LR].*$', '\1')
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/134bb/1)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!
Very confusing syntax when one is not that deep into that... at least when creating a statement. Understanding is ok with the doku beside me =)

Answer (score 4):

Another version (without fancy lookarounds :-) :

```
with v_data as (
  select '743H5-34L-56' val from dual
  union all
  select '123HD34-7L' val from dual
  union all 
  select '12HSS-34R' val from dual
  union all
  select '23Z67-4R-C23' val from dual
)
select 
  val, 
  regexp_replace(val, '^[^-]+-(\d+)[LR].*', '\1') 
from v_data
```

It matches

- the beginning of the string "^"
- one or more characters that are not a '-' "[^-]+"
- followed by a '-' "-"
- followed by one ore more digits (capturing them in a group) "(\d+)"
- followed by 'L' or 'R' "[LR]"
- followed by zero or more arbitrary characters ".*"